# ODBC Column Length Limitations

Tags: php, odbc, unixodbc, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I am working with InterSystems Cache database via ODBC and PHP.

I have run into an issue regarding column name lengths and invalid characters being returned in the column name text.

If the length of a column(field) name exceeds 31 chars the column name is returned with invalid characters.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3E2t.png)

If I explicitly define the field name with a max of 31 characters:

```
SELECT REBILL_AFTER_FINANCIAL_CLASS_CHANGE AS REBILL_AFTER_ FINANCIAL_CLASS_CHA
....................
.............
.......
```

The invalid characters no longer appear

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1fzz.png)

Has anyone else ever run into this issue or something similar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cache are you using? What version of the ODBC driver? If you turn on ODBC logging you should be able to see precisely what the database is passing to the client: http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20101/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BGOD_logging#BGOD_logging_logunix